# sharing on facebook using emulator

Tags: windows-phone-8, emulation

hiiii
all I want is to share data on facebook from my app but without device 
and I know that I can do that but I should add email from settings of the emulator
when I log in to yahoo mail it is works well
but when I try to log in hotmail mail problem sinning in appeared with code 0x8000ffff!

all what I want is to share data from my app using the emulator because I do not have device

```
    private void facebook_share_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //ShareLinkTask shareLinkTask = new ShareLinkTask();

        //shareLinkTask.Title = "Code Samples";
        //shareLinkTask.LinkUri = new Uri("https://www.facebook.com/", UriKind.Absolute);
        //shareLinkTask.Message = "Here are some great code samples for Windows Phone.";

        //shareLinkTask.Show();

        //ShareStatusTask sst = new ShareStatusTask();
        //sst.Status = "hello test";
        //sst.Show();
        ShareStatusTask shareStatusTask = new ShareStatusTask();
        shareStatusTask.Status = "Current Status: Developing WP8 apps.";
        shareStatusTask.Show();


    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Since, there is no active account in The Windows Phone Emulator, you cannot check whether it is working or not.

You need to have the real device to check whether `ShareStatusTask` is working or not. The task will work fine once the app is installed on a real device.

Comment: but i can access my facebook from the emulator i mean when i open the emulator and from start screen >>open internet >>then i can access my facebook account

Comment: You accessed your facebook using your emulator's browser. But ShareStatusTask is worked under the phone's default email account. You can't set phone default account in emulator. Try this and you will know practically what i am telling here. 

Goto Store in emulator -> tap install any free app -> it will asks you to give an email id -> but you cannot register since it is emulator.